# How to Copy the HTML Selection String with TextFormat information

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I have seen answers given for Copying HTML using javascript. Almost all answers were to use clonecontents as Below

```
function() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
};
```

But here if the tags are there in the selection region, then only formatting is getting copied, else it will be copied as a Text itself. I want to copy the formatting information associated with the selection. How can i achieve this.

Comment: explain more in my test no any problem or put some example

Comment: Assume <b>Hello<i>how are</i> you</b> is the text in editor. You are trying to copy only "are" from  the this text. My requirement is to copy the tags <b> and <i> also with are.

Comment: you Want get selected like this  <b>lo<i>how are</i> you</b> with parent format

Answer (score 0):

Test it can select with parent node

```
function(){
 var html = "";
 if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {

        var Node=sel.focusNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        //console.log(Node);
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        html = container.innerHTML;
        //
        Node.innerHTML=html;
        var co = document.createElement("div");
        co.appendChild(Node);
        html=co.innerHTML;

    }
 } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
 }
 return html;
}
```

Comment: Hi... This will work only for single parentNode. If we are applying multiple formatting to the text and try to copy the same, this logic will not work.